# GCC: Compiling an OpenCL host on Windows

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, mingw, opencl

I just wanted to try out using OpenCL under Windows.

***Abstract***: I got an **"`undefined reference to`" error** when I tried to compile (using the command `gcc my.o -o my.exe -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64" -l OpenCL`).

---

### My Code

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {   
    cl_platform_id platform;
    int err;

    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if(err < 0) {
        perror("There's No Platform!");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Some more code... */

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

### Makefile

```
all: addition

addition:
    gcc -c -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include" my.c -o my.o
    gcc my.o -o my.exe -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64" -l OpenCL
```

### Used Programs

- MinGW's **`gcc`**
- Visual Studio's **`nmake`**
- AMD's **OpenCL™ APP SDK** (that's where I took the OpenCL library and the `CL.h` file from)

### The Structure of APP SDK's Folders

```
%>tree /F "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64"
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade
Volumeseriennummer : D2DC-D765
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\AMD APP\LIB\X86_64
    libOpenCL.a
    OpenCL.lib
    OpenVideo64.lib

Es sind keine Unterordner vorhanden


%>tree /F "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include"
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade
Volumeseriennummer : D2DC-D765
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\AMD APP\INCLUDE
├───CAL
│       cal.h
│       calcl.h
│       cal_ext.h
│       cal_ext_counter.h
│       cal_ext_d3d10.h
│       cal_ext_d3d9.h
│
├───CL
│       cl.h
│       cl.hpp
│       cl_d3d10.h
│       cl_ext.h
│       cl_gl.h
│       cl_gl_ext.h
│       cl_platform.h
│       opencl.h
│
└───OpenVideo
        OpenVideo.h
        OVDecode.h
        OVDecodeTypes.h
        OVEncode.h
        OVEncodeTypes.h
```

### Error Message

```
        gcc addition.o -o addition.exe -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64" -l OpenCL
addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs@12'
addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\prog-x86\MinGW\bin\gcc.EXE": Rückgabe-Code "0x1"
Stop.
```

### My Questions

My questions are simple:

- Why doesn't my code compile how it is expected to?
- What can I do to get rid of this problem?

Thanks.

---

> ***UPDATE:*** The error message after **dropping the spaces** like described in @codaddict 's answer.
>
> *(Makefile)*
>
> ```
> all: addition
>
> addition:
>   gcc -c -I "C:\prog-x86\AMD-APP\include" addition.c -o addition.o
>   gcc addition.o -o addition.exe -LC:\prog-x86\AMD-APP\lib\x86_64 -lOpenCL
> ```
>
> *(Shelldata)*
>
> ```
> %>nmake
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility, Version 11.00.50727.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
>         gcc -c -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include" addition.c -o addition.o
> addition.c: In function 'main':
> addition.c:14:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by d
> efault]
> addition.c:23:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by d
> efault]
>         gcc addition.o -o addition.exe -LC:\prog-x86\AMD-APP\lib\x86_64 -lOpenCL
> addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs@12'
> addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
> addition.o:addition.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\prog-x86\MinGW\bin\gcc.EXE": Rückgabe-Code "0x1"
> Stop.
>
> %>
> ```

Comment: Can you try duplicating the backslashes in the gcc parameters? Like "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\..."? Otherwise they might get escaped and break the path. Unsure this is the reason but you never know.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your idea, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Does it say something different if you drop the -L parameter and instead give it the full path to OpenCL.lib? So remove -Lpath and add an unqualified "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\x86_64\OpenCL.lib" to tell gcc "hey here's a file you might find useful"?

Comment: @Thomas Did you mean something like `gcc addition.o -o addition.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64\OpenCL.lib" -l OpenCL`?

Comment: @Thomas `gcc` responses to command noted above: `c:/prog-x86/` *[...]* `/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lOpenCL` - `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Ok, never mind then, the fact that it returned that means it correctly finds the OpenCL library the way you're doing now - it just fails to link against it. Try -static flag...

Comment: Thanks for your proposal - But `gcc addition.o -o addition.exe -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64\" -l OpenCL -Wl,-static` doesn't help either. The `undefined reference` error is still there. - Do you know any other way how I maybe could handle this problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16731/discussion-between-thomas-and-fridojet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default MinGW distribution only ships tools for building x86 applications. You cannot link against the x64 version of the OpenCL library. So you either have to use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) or use the x86 version (change the library path to the x86 subfolder of the APP SDK).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
-l OpenCL
```

to

```
-lOpenCL
```

in the compile line.

The `-l` option of gcc expects the name of the library (without the lib prefix) right next to it without any space. Remember using `-lm` in school to link to `libm`?

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but it **didn't change anything**.

Comment: @fridojet: Can you also drop the space after `-L`?

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't help either. Thanks for your idea - Any other one?

Comment: I **edited my question** text in order to describe the reactions on running the Makefile after dropping the spaces.

Comment: You have also changed the library path to C:\prog-x86\AMD-APP\lib\x86_64. Are you sure the libraries are there ?

Comment: Yes, `C:\prog-x86\AMD-APP\lib\x86_64`'s just a symlink for `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64` on my system because some shell scripts don't want any space in the file path.

Comment: Thanks for your close sighting. - Now I've also tried the script without spaces after the option name, but with the old paths.

Comment: By the way: I first tried it with some spaces because **[die says](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)** that it's **also okay**. So, theoretically it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit g++ compiler on windows 10 is also in the bin folder:

```
"C:\MinGW\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe"
```

So this works for me:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ "C:\Users\...\main.cpp" -o
C:\Users\...\saxpy  -L "C:\Program Files\...\x64" -lOpenCL -I
"C:\...\OpenCL\sdk\include"
```

Notes:

1. -o output name
2. -L folder contains OpenCL.lib
3. -I folder contains header file e.g. CL/cl.h